# Rails 3 before_save not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error undefined method `before_save' for UsersController:Class. Is there any particular reason why before_save is undefined?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
```

....

```
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you post your `UsersController`?

Comment: Controllers don't have a `before_save`, only models.

Comment: ^Ah, thanks so much! I'm just learning rails, so I had dulicate code inside the controller.

Comment: Did this answer your Q?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you've fixed your error, I'd recommend putting your `before_save` actions into a single method (to keep it DRY):

```
  before_save :format_data

  def format_data
      self.email = email.downcase if email.present?
      if password.present?
          self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
          self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
      end
  end
```